# Visual studio issues after installing visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Windows 8 machine.
I had visual studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 installed on my computer.

I installed the visual studio 2013 preview, and the 8.1 WDK.

After I installed Visual Studio 2013, my old project in C++ wasn't able to be compiled (in Visual Studio 2012) so I uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 and the WDK.

But the issue remains, i cannot compile my C++ project. I get error message such as "Windows.h cannot be found" I looked at the include directory and saw that I have the following include: $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath). but when I open "Macros>>" I can't this macro "$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)".

I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 and reinstall them but it didn't fix the issue.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: I reinstalled vs 2012 but it didn't help :(

Comment: Ugh, installing alpha builds on a machine you need to get your job done is a really bad idea.  A system restore point might help.  That's a bit late though, uninstalling the older VS versions probably just added more trouble.

Comment: Still, is there away to remove all vs configurations?

Answer (score 0):

In order to build windows 8 apps in visual studio 2013, you must be using windows 8.1. (defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)). This is possibly the issue.

You also wouldn't see the windows sdk include path because the wdk would be uninstalled. I would recommend one of two things

1. get visual studio 2012 again, and download the [windows 8 sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx)
2. get windows 8.1, then install visual studio 2013, and use the [windows 8.1 sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949)

I know, its quite silly.