# Visual studio 2013 "A task was cancelled"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

After installing VS 2013 (Update 3) on windows 7 SP1 I have similar situation like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043676/visual-studio-issues-after-installing-visual-studio-2013) After installing windows 8.1 sdk visual studio cant build any win32 project and print output :

```
1>----— Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 —----
1>A task was canceled.
1>A task was canceled.
========= Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Check [your system clock](http://jirka.kulovany.net/index.php/12-main-thread/11-visual-studio-error-a-task-was-canceled)

Comment: Nobody change timezone. What timezone I must set? I've tried some values but this does not help.

Comment: There's no guarantee that's really the problem; it just might be. I guess I would set the timezone to whichever one you're actually in and then do a clean solution/rebuild. If that doesn't help, the problem is presumably something else.

Comment: Clean results the same as build "A task was cancelled"

Comment: The same problem happened to me when I changed the time zone while VS was open. Don't do that. VS is picky about its time zone.

Comment: I cancelled a task in visual studio and it used up 6.6GB of ram.

Comment: The same problem happened than I removed `.vs` directory as too big. My VS version is 16.7.5. Problem solved after reopening VS window

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Just to be complete,

Closing and reopening Visual Studio worked for me after I had changed the time zone and was getting the same errors as you.

Comment: Appears to also affect Visual Studio 2015.  Just did the same thing (changed time zone), had the same problem, and close/reopen solved it there too.

Comment: That is exactly what happened to me after changing the time zone.

Comment: This also happens after daylight savings (Windows 10, Studio 2015)

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 RC has the same problem.

Comment: Yup. VS2017 Pro too. +1

Comment: Colleague complained that my clock on the lock screen was wrong and confusing. Changed the time zone. Then watched this error crop up in the 4 visual studio instances I had opened. :P

Comment: Still occurs on VS2019 (only Enterprise edition tested) ^_^. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: In VS2019 (community) the same problem occerred too. Just close and reopen VS solved it without mingling with the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error when I installed VS2013 update 5. During the installation my VS was open. Prior to installation of the update, I was asked to close VS but I neglected. That might have been the reason for the error although not sure about the exact cause.

After installation, the installer prompted me to restart the computer and the error was gone after I restarted my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering similar problem with VS2015 update 3. Once this start happening I can't build application and can't start another instance Visual studio as it gives out of memory exception.

After looking through task lists I found out that there are many instance of *conhost.exe* and *MSBuild.exe* processes. So as temporary fix I kill all instances and try again building it is not perfect solution but works some times.

You can try run following batch commands.

```
Taskkill /IM MSBuild.exe /F
Taskkill /IM conhost.exe /F
```

Comment: Didn't solve anything here. But restarting VS2019 solved.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the time zone of system (Start>Settings>Time&language>Date&time>Time zone) to automatic, and then restarted the VS2019(on this I was facing the issue) in administrator mode. Issue got resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the "A task was cancelled" error, not after updating Visual Studio or changing the time clock, but when enabled editing to a file from my version control software.

Likewise, reloading Visual Studio fixed the error.