# Visual Studio 2015 Community C++ Build Failure: A task was cancelled

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I'm trying to build a brand new c++ console project in Visual Studio 2015 Community and getting the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>A task was canceled.
1>A task was canceled.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256957/visual-studio-2013-a-task-was-cancelled) it looks like the same problem. but the time has been recently synced:

[image]

And restarting Visual Studio doesn't change the build output. I've tried uninstalling Visual Studio and then reinstalling it, but the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Delete Debug/Release folders and restart MSVC.