# Dockerfile failed to deploy (not connected to docker) in Intellij Idea

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I'm new in Docker and just trying to follow instructions in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck6xQqSOlpw&t=73s).
I created very simple Dockerfile:

[image]

But deploying failed and the problem is that there is not much info:

[image]

Docker is up and running and I can connect to it from the IDE:

[image]

[image]

Docker info:

[image]

Comment: Have you installed Docker in your host system ?

Comment: Yes, I have it up and running.

Comment: Please attach screenshots from `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker` and `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker | Tools`.

Comment: In my case restarting the Idea solved problem :) In any situation)

Comment: I have the same issue but I use podman instead of docker. Effect is the same when I try to run the Dockerfile in order to build the image. While failing I can see an active "Docker" connection in the services which shows images, containers and alike.

Answer (score 16):

If you've recently changed settings in "Docker Desktop" make sure to restart your IDE, before trying to build images/run containers.

Comment: Gah what a classic IDE thing to do. My top answer is the same solution to a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256957/visual-studio-2013-a-task-was-cancelled/28797275#28797275

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the IDE on MacOs, you need to give it full disk access in the Privacy Settings in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while creating docker image for java.
I changed java "FROM openjdk:1.8" to "FROM openjdk:8"
build, restarted intellij and it worked.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [official instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html#enable_docker). Particularly this part:

> Configure the Docker daemon connection settings:
>
> Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Build, Execution,
> Deployment | Docker.
>
> Click ￼ to add a Docker configuration and specify how to connect to
> the Docker daemon.
>
> The connection settings depend on your Docker version and operating
> system. For more information, see Docker configuration.
>
> **The Connection successful message should appear at the bottom of the**
> **dialog**.

Comment: Just tried. The connection works with no issues (attached more screenshot to the question), but the Dockerfile file deployment still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I am exploring Docker for the first time too (although with JetBrains Rider rather than IntelliJ) and encountered the same error.

I resolved the error by right clicking on the dockerfile chevrons and building the image first:

[image: Build Image]

Once that had completed then I was able to successfully run the Dockerfile:
[image: Run Dockerfile]

[image: Success]

Hoping that Intellij works in much the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today but nothing from the other answers solved the problem. The only thing that helped is to remove the existing Docker configuration from `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment ->  Docker` and create a new one (completely the same): [image: Docker configuration screenshot]