# IDEA can't see docker desktop containers on ARM macOS

Tags: docker, macos, intellij-idea, docker-compose, docker-machine

I downloaded Docker Desktop for Mac and I can run docker-compose up but when I try to run a functional test I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
```

and when I check the logs I see that it is about docker machine I believe.

```
[main] ERROR o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
[main] ERROR o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
[main] ERROR o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception ShellCommandException (Exception when executing docker-machine status ). Root cause InvalidExitValueException (Unexpected exit value: 1, allowed exit values: [0], executed command [docker-machine, status, ], output was 122 bytes:
Docker machine "" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.)
[main] ERROR o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
```

but I believe Docker Desktop should be enough for MacOS, not confident though. I tried to create a docker machine but I couldn't because it needs a virtualbox but virtualbox doesn't support M1 macs. Don't know what to do here to be honest.

I can see the container up and running in Docker Desktop,the docker-compose up also runs. It seems like IntellijIDEA can't see it? Also when I try to add Docker to IntellijIDEA from Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker, I also get the error

```
Cannot connect: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Details: [2] No such file or directory)
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Edit: I actually checked var/run and there is no such file as docker.sock. Why is this, I am so confused.

Comment: Can you check this and it seems this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447057/dockerfile-failed-to-deploy-not-connected-to-docker-in-intellij-idea

Comment: @devforhelp thanks a lot for the thread, Idea has full disk access and I've restarted it a few times so that doesn't fix it sadly. Also the thread you linked can connect to the docker from intellij idea while mine can't