# Visual Studio 2022 "A task was cancelled" after build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022. Now I have a similar problem with [Visual studio 2013 "A task was cancelled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256957/visual-studio-2013-a-task-was-cancelled).
A few moments ago, everything went alright. However I suddenly found that when I try to build my cpp project, VS only output

```
1>----— Build started: Project: MyConsoleApp, Configuration: Release x64 —----
```

After about 5 minutes, it becomes

```
1>----— Build started: Project: MyConsoleApp, Configuration: Release x64 —----
1>A task was canceled.
1>A task was canceled.
========= Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

All my cpp projects have the same problem now. My time zone is correct. I have tried to reopen VS, restart my computer and reinstall Visual Studio, but this problem still exists.

Comment: Does restarting VS do anything?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening Visual Studio, as suggested by both common sense and the answer to the linked question?

Comment: Randomly I see this in Visual Studio 2019 and closing and repopening the IDE fixes this every time.

Comment: I have tried, but useless...@AndyG,@paddy

Comment: You may have to ask Microsoft.

Comment: I suggest you try to reinstall VS or repair it, of course you could also go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) to report this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem as you, since February 28th, VS2022 could not build any project, until today, I uninstalled the anti-virus software (360 Security Guard) installed on my computer, it returned to normal work, I think this is due to the anti-virus software update caused by the incompatible VS2022,   You can try uninstalling the anti-virus software installed on your computer, which may solve the problem